# C# Method passed as a parameter able to access private members of the receiving class

Tags: c#, delegates

I think the title is kinda hard to understand. That's why I will try to explain myself a bit more clearly:
I have a ClickLabel which is supposed to implement a certain method that can be passed as a parameter during its construction or later on to perform a certain action.
The point is that not each ClickLabel I will be implementing is supposed to execute the same task.

I might just be too tired right now to solve the thing on my own but I wanted to get some professional answers from you as to how I can solve this as easily as possible because I know that otherwise it will haunt me forever.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a `System.Action` and pass that to your label?

Comment: If the method your delagate is wrapping can access private members, then you should be able to.  However, since this can change it's not a good idea. Use an event or interface to differentiate the various tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got you right you should pass a delegate as a parameter and then assign it as event handler to ClickLabel

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create an IClickLabel interface that defines the method that you want to execute then you can define different classes that implement IClickLabel. The param on your constructor would be of Type IClickLabel which ensures that each class you pass in has the required method available to call - and each class implementing IClackLabel can implement the logic in the method differently.